# How to restore lvm partition without config file?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

Today I did update my ubuntu server.
The device structure is looks like to below

```
1) sda1     # new os
2) sdb1     # origin /boot partition
3) sdb2     # origin swap partition
4) sdb3     # origin lvm
5) sdc1     # origin lvm
6) sdd1     # origin lvm
```

And I occurs huge mistake at partitioning that I've delete origin lvm configurations.
I expect origin lvm meta backup is in the sdb3 so I can't access origin meta backup files.
And, I did re configure manually(pvcreate, vgcreate, lvcreate and so on), but I couldn't mount with error(`VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`)
How could I recover that lvm partition?
Or, how can I access origin files without lvm?
Please help thanks!
(I didn't format yet, I just delete in configuration)